# According to Smarta, all of three of the "Trimurti" are equal. But why isn't Brahma given the same significance as Vishnu and Shiva?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, gods, vedanta, brahma

Even Puri Shankaracharya said that chanting the name of Narayana and Shiva would have the same benefits. However, why don't anyone give such importance to Brahma?

Comment: It's not that *Brahmã* isn't given that position at an equal par at all or not. It's more because, he's [cursed](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/264/why-are-temples-devoted-to-brahma-so-rare)  to  [not be worshipped](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19874/17833) as such. There's more of theological and/or soteriological reasoning behind it.

Comment: Leave alone gods since Puri shankaracharya is advaitin just by chanting his name also gives the same effect as that of lord himself.if one really believes in advaita one should chant their name instead of some other entity as god. But im not advaitin its question to advaitin..

Answer (score 1):

Smarta is just a term given to those who follow Smritis. However, now it means followers of Adi Shankara. Assuming you mean the latter, Smartas follow the  shanmatha system and the panchayatana worship.

Panchayatana Puja consists of worshipping five deities of Hinduism viz - Ganesha, Shiva, Vishnu, Devi and Surya. The sixth deity, under shanmatha system, is Agni or Karthikeya, with the latter being followed currently. Adi Shankara wrote devotional stotras for [five deities](https://shankaraamrutham.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/shankara-stotra-saahithya/) except Agni.

These forms of worship were revived by Adi Shankara. These forms of pooja were already existing. For example, Matysa Purana says

> Adityam gananAtham cha devim rudram cha keshavam |
> PanchaDaivatyamityuktam sarva karmasu pujayeth ||
>
> Surya, Ganesha, Devi, Rudra and Keshava - These five deities are to be
> worshiped in all auspicious occasions.

Similarly, the worship of these deities can be quoted from [Devi Bhagavata](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana70.html) and is found in the kamakoti math website.

> Do worship Ganesha to remove the obstacles, Surya Deva for good
> health, Agni Deva for purification, Vishnu for wealth and power, Siva
> for knowledge and Sivani for salvation.

Today, the Smartha maths of shankara worship and celebrate the festivals of Ganesha (Ganesha Chaturthi)
Vishnu, (Krishna jayanthi, Rama Navami)
Siva (daily pooja, shivarathri)
Devi (navarathri)
Surya (ratha sapthami)
karthikeya ()